# Material UI image on Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, svg, toolbar, material-ui

I'm new to Reactjs and Material-ui. I have tried to change the title text to a SVG logo but I am so lost with this . HELP!

```
/**
*
* UserPanelToolbar
*
*/

import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Toolbar from 'react-md/lib/Toolbars';

class UserPanelToolbar extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line     react/prefer-stateless-function
    render() {
        const items = this.props.items;
        return (
            <Toolbar
                title = "TITLE"
                actions = {items}
            />
        );
    }
}
UserPanelToolbar.propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.element).isRequired,
};

export default UserPanelToolbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a closing tag to your Appbar element (remove the self closing tag) and put the image inside. Now I don't know where you want to place it exactly but if you give me more details I'm willing to help.

```
<Toolbar title = "TITLE" actions = {items}>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/25/25" alt="Kitten" height="25" width="25" />
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you want to use images in the AppBar, but it is possible to put an  element in both the iconElementLeft and iconElementRight props.